# CSS Text over html5 video Mobile Issue

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am working on this Text and button over an Html5 Video, and I am trying not to use any media query to fix the mobile issue I am having. The problem is I am using the car-image-overlay class of bootstrap 4 to display the div that contains the text over the video. Using other bootstraps 4 classes to align centre left and all. But in Mobile (ex: iphone 5e) everything breaks, the button, h1 and p seem to not adjust so it covers the whole video an getting out of frame like this picture. I thought bootstrap would take care of this, but maybe i am not doing this the right way. I am using col-lg and xs as well, still no use

[image]

```css
.cta-video-section .cta-video-container {
  position: relative;
}
.cta-video-section .cta-video-container video {
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
.cta-video-section .cta-video-container h2 {
  color: white;
}
.cta-video-section .cta-video-container p {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
.cta-video-section .cta-video-container button {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN"
        crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
<div class="cta-video-section">
        <div class="cta-video-container">
                <video id="cta-video" autoplay loop muted>
                    <source src="http://www.icutpeople.com/wp-content/themes/icutpeople/assets/video/waynesworld.mp4" type="video/mp4">                Your
                    browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>
                <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex align-items-center" id="cta-video-texts">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="text-left col-xs-1 col-lg-4 ">
                                <h2 class="card-title ">H2 Locations Headline</h2>
                                <p class="card-text ">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional
                                    content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                                <div class="">
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger  btn-lg " id="cta-video-button">                                
                                            Watch Video CTA
                                    </button>
            
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
</div>
 


    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid using a media query? It's not a one-size fits all type of deal... your font size is simply too big at that device size.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to use a media query?

I think you can solve that if you will change the title the paragraph and the button text and size as well on the mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the Font size or line height of the content you had used in media queries. The Only problem is bigger font size for smaller devices